# Process the same stdin two time and append the outputs

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have a json file that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+down",
        "command": "-editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+f12",
        "command": "editor.action.peekDefinition",
        "when": "editorHasDefinitionProvider && editorTextFocus && !inReferenceSearchEditor && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
    }
]
//  {
//      "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
//      "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
//  },
//  {
//      "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
//      "command": "-workbench.view.debug",
//      "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled"
//  }
```

I want to sort this file.

`jq` give error if there is `//` at the beginning of line as this is not a valid json.

So to sort this file, the command I came up with is:

```
grep -v '^[ ]*//' keybindings.json | jq 'sort_by(.key)'
```

But I do not want to discard the commented lines. So, to get the commented lines, the command I came up with is:

```
grep '^[ ]*//' keybindings.json
```

Now to solve my problem, what I can simply do is:

```
#!/bin/bash

SORTED_JSON=$(grep -v '^[ ]*//' keybindings.json | jq 'sort_by(.key)')
COMMENTED_JSON=$(grep '^[ ]*//' keybindings.json)

echo "$SORTED_JSON" >keybindings.json
echo "$COMMENTED_JSON" >>keybindings.json
```

But there is a catch.

I have to do this in one command. This is because, I am doing this via a vscode settings.

```
"filterText.commandList": [
    {
        "name": "Sort VSCode Keybindings",
        "description": "Sorts keybindings.json by keys. Select everything except the comment in fist line. Then run this command",
        "command": "jq 'sort_by(.key)'"
    }
]
```

The `command` take the selected text as stdin, process it, then output the processed text.

So, as far i understand, i have to read the stdin two times (once with `grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)'` and the second time with `grep '^[ ]*//'`). And append the two command output in stdout.

How can I solve this problem?

**Update 1:**

I have tried both

```
cat keybindings.json| {grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)' ; grep '^[ ]*//'}
```

and

```
cat keybindings.json| (grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)' ; grep '^[ ]*//')
```

These does not show the commented lines.

**Update 2:**

The following seems to be close to what I was expecting. But here commented lines come before the uncommented lines.

```
$ cat keybindings.json| tee >(grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)') >(grep '^[ ]*//') > /dev/null 2>&1
    //  {
    //      "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
    //      "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
    //  },
    //  {
    //      "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
    //      "command": "-workbench.view.debug",
    //      "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.debug.enabled"
    //  }
[
  {
    "key": "alt+down",
    "command": "-editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+f12",
    "command": "editor.action.peekDefinition",
    "when": "editorHasDefinitionProvider && editorTextFocus && !inReferenceSearchEditor && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
  }
]
```

**Update 3:**

```
cat keybindings.json| (tee >(grep '^[ ]*//'); tee >(grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)'))
```

or,

```
cat keybindings.json| {tee >(grep '^[ ]*//'); tee >(grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)')}
```

also seems to give the same output as Update 3 (commented lines come before the uncommented lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to interpolate mixed comment lines and non-comment lines; you have to treat them as separate blocks and process them separately.

If you didn't mind the commented lines being output first you could use `awk` like this:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^ *\/\//) { print } else { print | "jq \"sort_by(.key)\"" } }' keybindings.json
```

But since you want the comment lines to come at the end you need to store the comment lines and output them later:

```
awk '
    # Define a convenience variable for the jq process
    BEGIN {
        jq = "jq \"sort_by(.key)\""
    }

    # Each line hits this. Either we save the comment or we feed it to jq
    {
        if ($0 ~ /^ *\/\//) { c[++i] = $0 }
        else { print | jq }
    }
    
    # Close the pipe to get its output and then print the saved comment lines
    END {
        close (jq);
        for (i in c) { print c[i] }
    }
' keybindings.json
```

Now, regarding your "*I have to do this in one command*". Remember that there is nothing stopping you creating your own commands (programs, scripts). Put the necessary set of commands into a file, make the file executable, and put it into a directory that's in your `$PATH`. I have always used `$HOME/bin` and I have the equivalent of `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"` in my `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your comments into strings, sort your arrays, and then turn the comment strings into comments again.

Turning the comments into strings is done by

1. Detect lines starting with `//` (with optional indentation with spaces).
2. Replace any existing `"` on those lines with `\"`, and
3. Double quote the line.

```bash
sed '\:^ *//: { s/"/\\"/g; s/.*/"&"/; }'
```

Then, sort the arrays:

```bash
jq 'if type == "array" then sort_by(.key) else . end'
```

At the end, turn back the comment strings into comments:

1. Detect lines starting with `"//` (with optional spaces between `"` and `//`) and ending with `"`.
2. Remove the first `"` and the `"` at the end of those lines.
3. Replace each `\"` by `"`.

```bash
sed '\:^"\( *//.*\)"$: { s//\1/; s/\\"/"/g; }'
```

The pipeline in full reading from standard input:

```bash
sed '\:^ *//: { s/"/\\"/g; s/.*/"&"/; }' |
jq 'if type == "array" then sort_by(.key) else . end' |
sed '\:^"\( *//.*\)"$: { s//\1/; s/\\"/"/g; }'
```

This assumes that your data does not already contain escaped double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have done some research, would like to answer my question as well. For single line command:

```
cat keybindings.json | (tee /tmp/program-code-binding.json | grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)'; cat /tmp/program-code-binding.json | grep '^[ ]*//')
```

If you want to use script then:

```
#!/bin/bash

THESTDIN=$(cat)

SORTED_JSON=$(echo "$THESTDIN" | grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)')
COMMENTED_JSON=$(echo "$THESTDIN" | grep '^[ ]*//')

echo "$SORTED_JSON"
echo "$COMMENTED_JSON"
```

There is an edge case for the script. [`THESTDIN=$(cat)` will hang indefinitely if there is nothing in the pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343371/1772898). To deal with this issue, the script will actually look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

__=""
THESTDIN=""

read -N1 -t1 __  && {
    (( $? <= 128 ))  && {
        IFS= read -rd '' _stdin
        THESTDIN="$__$_stdin"
    }
}

SORTED_JSON=$(echo "$THESTDIN" | grep -v '^[ ]*//' | jq 'sort_by(.key)')
COMMENTED_JSON=$(echo "$THESTDIN" | grep '^[ ]*//')

echo "$SORTED_JSON"
echo "$COMMENTED_JSON"
```

Comment: No `THESTDIN=$(cat)` will not hang indefinitely if there's nothing in the pipe. Only if the writing end of the pipe (assuming stdin is the reading end of a pipe) is never closed. The linked Q&A was using `var="$(< /dev/stdin)"` which is wrong on Linux or Cygwin at least. You could switch to `ksh93` and use `var=$(<&0)` if the point is to avoid running `cat`.

Comment: In the first script where i used `THESTDIN=$(cat)`, how can i close the writing end (i use bash and zsh)?

Comment: `cat` will read until the ends of its input whether it's a pipe or not, when it's a pipe as in `somecmd | your-script`, the writing end is typically closed when `somecmd` exits, though `somecmd` could choose to close it early by doing `close(1)`. In any case you shouldn't have anything to do about it in your script as your script is meant to read its **whole** input. If the input never ends as in `yes | yourscript` or `sleep infinity | yourscript` or `</dev/zero yourscript`, there's nothing you can do about it, whatever problem there is is with whatever feeding input to your script.